# Can I play investigations after the relevant assassination?

Tags: assassins-creed

I returned to the assassins bureau and then completed my assigned assassination before I had completed all the available investigations in the area.  Is there any way to play the investigations that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the memory block where you missed the investigation. instead of continuing from the last session.